# I need to calculate the optimal value of a function involving integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations, stochastic-calculus

I am working on a capacity sharing problem which involves the function as the picture below.
I want to calculate the derivative of the function with respect to the variable $a_1.$ The profit function is
$$
    E(\pi^1)= \int_{0}^{n a_1} b_1  x f(x) dx +\int_{n a_1}^{\infty}b_1 (na_1) f(x) dx+ \\
    \int_{na_1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{ma_2}p_1  \min (x-na_1,ma_2-y) f(y) f(x) dy dx - c \times na_1
$$

How to do that in Mathematica? I have broken down the $\min$ function to this,
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    E(\pi^1)&= \int_{0}^{n a_1} b_1  x f(x) dx +\int_{n a_1}^{\infty}b_1 (na_1) f(x) dx+ \\
    &\int_{0}^{ma_2}\int_{0}^{na_1+ma_2-y} p_1 (x-na_1) f(x) f(y) dx dy - \\
    & \int_{0}^{ma_2}\int_{na_1+ma_2-y}^{\infty}p_1(ma_2-y)f(x) f(y) dx dy -c \times na_1
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Also I need to calculate the Hessian of the multivariable function that contains the variables $a_1, a_2.$ Any guidance will be appreciated.

**$b_1, p_1, c, n,  m$ are constants. $x, y$ are random variables and $f(x), f(y)$ are the probability density functions.

Codes:

```
f[a1_, a2_] := Integrate[bxg[x], {x, 0, na1}] +
               Integrate[bna1*g[x], {x, na1, Infinity}] +
               Integrate[(x - na1)*g[x]*g[y], {y, ma2, Infinity}, {x, 0, na1 + ma2 - y}] +
               Integrate[(ma2 - y)*g[x]*g[y], {y, ma2, Infinity}, {x, na1 + ma2 - y, Infinity}] - cna1
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Have you made any attempt at solving your problem using WL? Please edit your question and add the code you have tried.

Comment: I have added the snapshot of the code that I tried, but it gives me a long answer which is difficult to interpret.

Comment: An image of code is unusable. It cannot be copied/pasted/evaluated. Take a look at [this](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/58370) for help on how to include WL code in a post.

Comment: For some reason the code indent is throwing some errors. I am pasting the codes below in the raw-input format.

Comment: f[a1_, a2_] := Integrate[b*x*g[x], {x, 0, n*a1}] + Integrate[b*n*a1*g[x], {x, n*a1, Infinity}] + Integrate[(x - n*a1)*g[x]*g[y], {y, m*a2, Infinity}, 
    {x, 0, na1 + ma2 - y}] + Integrate[(m*a2 - y)*g[x]*g[y], {y, m*a2, Infinity}, {x, n*a1 + m*a2 - y, Infinity}] - c*n*a1

Comment: D[f[a1, a2], {{a1, a2}, 2}]

Comment: You could start small and manually use Leibniz rule for the first integral, the second, maybe the third just to see how to do it first before using Mathematica then compare your results to that computed by Mathematica.  Basically, I would not try to differentiate all of that at once in Mathematica before trying to just differentiate parts of it separately.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have tried that. Mathematica gives some long answers when I try to even solve a single integration. BTW, I wanted to know if there is some method where Mathematica can handle the "min" function within an integration.

Comment: Does taking direct second derivative gives a different answer in Mathematica than taking derivative twice? I am facing the same issue. While I am applying direct second derivative I am getting a different answer as compared to the method where I take derivative twice.